# How does the GIMP function "perspective" work?

Tags: gimp

The function "perspective" looks like a 3*3-matrix with sine och cosines and is it translation, scaling, rotation, some combination or other? How does it work? Is "perspective" the real proper name since it seems more like a rotation combined with a scaling? Thanks for any pointer about the function "perspective" where you can change the perspective of the image so that it looks like it was taken from another angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/manual/pdf/ch10.ps.

Comment: Thank you. The grid helped me understand better. I now wonder what implementations are avilable and will look more.

Comment: Glad to help! :D In fact transformation matrices are used quite often in both vector and raster graphics software (e.g. http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.44#Transform_dialog – there's a tab called "matrix"), but it's not always so explicitly presented.